# Problem in using perturbation method to solve an ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, perturbation-theory

I am trying to solve the period of the solution to this ordinary differential equation:
$$k \cdot r \cdot arctan(r'/r) \cdot (r^2+r'^2)^2= r'(r \cdot r''-2r'^2-r^2)$$

The numerical solution when $k=-20/9$ and initial condition $r(0)=r_0=0.9, r'(0)=0$ is
[image: numerical solution for $k=-20/9, r(0)=r_0=0.9, r'(0)=0$]

So I tried this perturbation:
$$r(t)=A \cdot [1-\epsilon \cdot cos(\nu t)]$$
where $A=r_0/(1-\epsilon)$.

After plugging this into the ODE, I got
$$A^3 (1+A^2k) \cdot \nu sin(\nu t) \cdot \epsilon -\frac{1}{2} A^3 (2+4A^2k+\nu^2) \cdot \nu sin(2\nu t) \cdot \epsilon^2 + O(\epsilon^3) = 0$$

It seems there is no way for me to eliminate the $\epsilon$ term.

Could you tell me what I should do? I'd really appreciate your help!

Comment: Is $\theta = t$?

Comment: @ caverac Yes, $\theta$ is $t$. I am sorry to have made this typo.

Comment: I have now changed all $\theta$ to $t$ to be consistent.

Comment: I think it makes more sense to have

$$
r(t) = \frac{\epsilon}{2}(\cos\nu t - 1) + r_0
$$

Comment: @ caverac Thanks for the suggestion. But the $\epsilon$ term is $-\frac{1}{2}r_0^2(1+kr_0^2)\nu sin(\nu t) \epsilon$ and it seems I sill cannot find a way to make it zerp, except for letting $\nu =0$, which is not what the numerical result is showing.

Comment: I have found the stationary solution for this equation is $r_0(t)=\sqrt{-1/k}$ and by trying a perturbation $r(t)=\sqrt{-1/k}+\epsilon cos(\nu t)$, we will have a vanishing $\epsilon$ term and the rest is $-\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{-\frac{1}{k}}(\nu^2-2) sin(2\nu t) \epsilon^2 +O(\epsilon^3)$. This gives me a period of $2\pi/\sqrt{2}=4.44$, invariant of the $k$ while the numerical result has a period of $5.09$. Not too bad. But is there a better approximation?